# web api in subdirectory application

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api2

I am creating a hub site with links to various apps, which are all stored in subdirectories under the main hub site. One of these apps has a web api, which works fine when debugging on localhost. However, when I publish to the subdirectory, I get a 404 error when trying to hit the api. Based on other questions, I made sure to "create application" in IIS for the subdirectory. This is my first web api attempt and I don't know what else to try, or even what other info I should give to clarify the problem.

**hub site**: apps.somesite.com
**app site**: apps.somesite.com/someapp/

**working api**: localhost:12345/api/tasks

**404 not working api, app automatically tries to use this one**: apps.somesite.com/api/tasks
**404 not working api, I type this one in**: apps.somesite.com/someapp/api/tasks (

Here's my controller:

```
namespace TaskTracker.Controllers
{
    [RoutePrefix("api")]
    public class TasksController : ApiController
    {

        ModelEntities taskTrackerApi = new ModelEntities();

        // Returns a list of all tasks
        [Route("tasks")]
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<taskTracker_getTasks_Result> getTasks()
        {
            return taskTrackerApi.taskTracker_getTasks().AsEnumerable();
        }

        // To create a new task
        [Route("add/{arkona}")]
        [HttpPost]
        public int addTask(string arkona)
        {
            return taskTrackerApi.taskTracker_addTask(arkona);
        }

        // To update a task
        [Route("update")]
        [HttpPut]
        public int updateTask([FromBody]TaskTracker.Models.Task task)
        {
            int id = task.Id;
            string taskName = task.TaskName;
            string link = task.Link;
            DateTime lastUpdate = task.LastUpdate;
            string lastUpdatedBy = task.LastUpdatedBy;
            DateTime dueDate = task.DueDate;
            string notes = task.Notes;

            return taskTrackerApi.taskTracker_updateTask(id, taskName, link, lastUpdate, lastUpdatedBy, dueDate, notes);
        }

        // To delete a task
        [Route("delete/{id:int}")]
        [HttpDelete]
        public int deleteTask(int id)
        {
            return taskTrackerApi.taskTracker_deleteTask(id);
        }

        // Returns a list of the dealerships
        [Route("dealers")]
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<taskTracker_getDealers_Result> getDealers()
        {
            return taskTrackerApi.taskTracker_getDealers().AsEnumerable();
        }

    }
}
```

Here's my api config:

```
namespace Task_Tracker
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            // Use camelcase for JSON data
            config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, here is my service in angular to call the api:

```
app.service('taskService', ['$http', function ($http) {

    this.getTasks = function () {
        return $http.get('/api/tasks');
    };

    this.createTask = function (arkona) {
        return $http.post('/api/add/' + arkona);
    };

    this.updateTask = function (task) {
        return $http.put('/api/update', task);
    };

    this.deleteTask = function (id) {
        return $http.delete('/api/delete/' + id);
    };

    this.getDealers = function () {
        return $http.get('/api/dealers');
    };

}]);
```

Comment: In IIS Manager, select the folder where you put your API application. Then over at the right of the window, under 'Browse Application', click 'Browse ...'. Is the URL that it takes you to the same URL that you are trying to use when you get the 404?

Comment: Well, it takes me to the default html page for the app, and that loads fine. But the page has an error, which is a 404 for the api route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There ended up being two problems. One, the app was being published to a too-old version of IIS; and two, I needed to remove the leading forward slash on my angularjs http get call.

**Incorrect:**

```
return $http.get('/api/tasks');
```

**Correct:**

```
return $http.get('api/tasks');
```