# post and get link defaults to domain root in vuejs

Tags: api, vue.js, subdomain, root

In my vue application, all the links point to the domain sub-folder as they should but when I perform a get or post, the links are always pointing to the domain root instead of domain subfolder where the code is deployed.

For instance, my code is deployed to www.sitedomain.com/appfolder.
However, get and post point to www.sitedomain.com/api/getdata/... instead of www.sitedomain.com/appfolder/api/getdata/...

Any ideas what I need to do to get the get/post links to point to the sub-folder?

Comment: I'm confused. Your first paragraph says your code in a subfolder links to the subfolder but GET/POST calls do not. In your second paragraph you say that they go the subfolder and you want it to go to root. Which is it?

Comment: What I mean is that if you mouse over a link, it correctly points to the sub-folder but if you for instance click on a button to save (perform http post eg http.$post(‘/api/saveChanges’, this.model), it always defaults to the root domain (wwwww.sitedomain.com/api/saveChanges/...) instead of www.sitedomain.com/appfolder/api/saveChanges/...).

Comment: I think the second paragraph has its examples back-to-front. That aside, if you have a leading slash `/` it will be treated as relative to the root. This should be consistent between both links and axios. I would guess that your links do not have a leading slash but your axios calls do.

Comment: Hi @RaymondCamden, thanks for responding to this questions. I have been able to solve the problem by removing the leading forward slash in the api call.  i.e instead of http.$post('/api/saveChanges...'), I changed it to http.$post('api/saveChanges...') and everything works fine when published again. I hope this helps someone.

Comment: Oh... and thanks to @psnoonan. I got this answer from his post at  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36872458/web-api-in-subdirectory-application

Comment: Yes... thanks @skirtle.  The lading slash is the culprit.  Thanks for your help.